# Cannot parse a date year in java

Tags: java, date

I have a date that is in the `MM/dd/yy` format. I get it from an XML file. Let's say, for example, it's `10/03/11`.

I execute the following code on it:

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    System.out.println("dateStr: " + dateStr);
    date = sdf.parse(dateStr);
    System.out.println("dateStr After: " + sdf.format(date));
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error when formatting date");
}
```

The output is:

```
dateStr: 10/03/11
dateStr After: 10/03/0011
```

I can not seem to get it to be `10/03/2011`. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When the date you are parsing has year with two chars, your `simpleDateFormatter` should also `yy` only.

**EDIT:**

```
// First convert to date object
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
System.out.println("dateStr: " + dateStr);

Date date = sdf.parse(dateStr);

SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
sdf2.format(date);

// Then, format it to get 2011 with another date format.
System.out.println("dateStr After: " + sdf.format(date));
System.out.println("dateStr NEXT After: " +  sdf2.format(date));
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. For some reason I was thinking that it was supposed to be the format you wanted it in, not the format it is currently in.

Answer (score 4):

It's a parse exception... Use `MM/dd/yy` instead of `MM/dd/yyyy`.

Like:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
```